# Migrating windows from one PC to another (same exact hardware)

Tags: windows, windows-10, migration

I have a case of OS migration that I have not dealt with before.

So the story is: airline checked baggage broke my built computer (fragile stickers, what a joke). I am ordering the same exact hardware. The SSD is definitely not broken in the previous computer.

My question is is it possible to just plug in my SSD without reinstalling windows and all my applications (after building the new computer, new hardware of the same model and series etc)? I think it would work fine. The parts are arriving in 2 days so I won't be able to try until they arrive.

Comment: as long as everything is _exact_, it should work fine.

Comment: You don't indicate what version of Windows; although it doesn't matter in ALL version activation is partially based on hardware with OEM hardware; So no; What you want isn't possible

Comment: Wow, amazing. I'm shocked at how poorly interpreted and and received this question was. I've been an avid stack exchange user for years now but I'll think twice about using superuser again. 1. Did you guys even understand the situation? I have a custom built computer that was broken by airlines, I just want to migrate my ssd from the old broken computer to my new one. What the heck is with the down vote? Wow, simply wow.

Comment: @ramhound so are you not familiar with the fact that some people such as myself build custom computers and have legal windows licenses? Is that too far out of the realm of possibility for you guys?

Comment: Stop worrying about a SINGLE vote you don't agree with

Comment: @rpg711 You didn't mention that fact.  How are we suppose to know the most common situation is OEM hardware.  Of course activation is still based on the hardware

Comment: @ramhound I'm sorry, this just was not the best place to post this question, I've gotten my answer elsewhere

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear because in fairness to people trying to help, the question cannot be correctly answered as written.  You don't mention the type of license.  You don't really describe whether the only surviving item is the SSD (it's unbelievable that nothing else would have survived airline handling).  You provide snarky comments implying unusual conditions, which nobody would know from the question, but even there, you don't make definitive statements.  If you can clarify the question so it is unambiguous and answerable from the information provided, I'll retract the vote.

Comment: That's a level of specificity that was unnecessary in the other computer enthusiast board that I sought my answer from. And yes, it does work perfectly fine. Same exact hardware, same model, same everything, just needed to replace the broken hardware that was covered by insurance. I don't need you to believe whether or not everything broke (the concept makes me want to laugh, honestly), I just wanted a simple yes/no answer, not deep analysis of a really, really straightforward question. I have absolutely no problems with activation. If I do I have a clear cut support case with claims docs. ;-)

Comment: @rpg711, glad this worked out for you.  Just FYI, it isn't as straightforward as you think.  It depends on the type of license, whether you reuse the old motherboard, etc.  Without those details, answers would either need to exhaustively cover all possibilities, or could be wrong.  That was the problem.  It isn't clear if you did a new activation.  If not, you could still be in a situation where at some point, Microsoft will become aware of the swap and might decide to inactivate the license.  Depending on the details, your rights, and the hoops you need to jump through could be different.

Comment: Hardware differences is actually the least of your problems. There could be substantial differences and besides removing old drivers and installing new ones the OS should generally run just fine on new hardware. The bigger issues are whether the HDD is encrypted, and the licensing. Microsoft doesn't look at the model of the hardware it is running on, but the IDs, which are unique for every piece of hardware. You'll probably have to reactivate on the licensing side. On the encryption side, so long as you have the decryption key you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to move over the hard drive just fine if the hardware is the same

You may need to buy a new windows license if it's windows 7 or before

If it's windows 10 It should get the product key from the new computer's EFI/UEFI just fine

As for Windows 8/8.1,your on your own to find that out as I haven't really use Windows 8

If the hardware is different, you may need to go into safe mode with networking so windows can get as many drivers as it can

Then manually update any missing drivers yourself by using the manufacturer's website

Comment: The question contains a lot of ambiguous information, which makes it hard to answer.  There's 2 aspects, drivers and license.  You're right on the drivers, although the OP claims the hardware is identical, so the drivers should be the same in this case.  Double check your information on the license to verify that Win10 can be transferred to another machine by just moving the drive.  The information is maintained at Microsoft and the license would have been associated with the old key.

Comment: @fixer1234, I've moved from 3 computers using the same install of windows 10 with no problem, except for 4 drivers

Comment: Does your experience reflect "capability" or license terms?  Even if limited by the license, there's always a grace period where it will work.  Beyond that, it will work unless or until Microsoft decides to enforce the license.  Check the EULA to verify whether you're allowed to do it under the terms.

Comment: It's been about 3 or 4 months since I changed computers and kept the same HDD, I had bought and installed Windows 10 on that computer as I was finally tired of Windows 7, I also work at a tech store (as stated in my bio) and I have messed around a but with swapping hard drives with Windows 7 and 10

Comment: Windows 10 (if it's a EFI/UEFI install) will grab the product key from the computer if it came pre-installed with windows 10

Comment: It's the OS that's licensed, and Microsoft relates the hardware, OS installation and product key.  Where the key is stored doesn't affect license transferability.  check out https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm.  OEM license is tied to the original motherboard.  Retail license can be transferred to another machine.

Comment: again I have messed around with windows 10 swaps at my work from OEM installs (not for customers, just for testing) and as long as EFI/UEFI is used, They haven't been deactivated... yet, and it's been about 4 months with the first one and it's still activated

Comment: "yet" is the operative word.  :-)

Comment: yes, it's been working just fine and hasn't deactivated yet... you never know if I may switch it or purposely mess it up

Comment: Another BIOS install though has already gotten the "activate windows" watermark though

Comment: Storing the key there makes it easier for Microsoft to enforce the license if and when they decide to.  You activate the license on machine A and Microsoft has a record that Machine A's key is associated with that OS installation on the drive.  You move the drive to machine B.  Machine B's key doesn't match Microsoft's records for the OS installation on that drive.  The verification is done when you connect to the Internet.

Comment: I recall a statistic that there is somewhere in the ballpark of 2 billion computers with Microsoft products installed.  They probably don't want to verify every license every time those computers boot up.  So it's likely that some scheme is employed to sample or check at some interval.  With all the pushback they got on the Win10 roll-out, they might also be allowing things to cool down before aggressively enforcing licenses.  They need to ensure their system gets it right because there would be hell to pay if after that roll-out, a lot of users got incorrect invalidations.

Comment: Accepted as answer, because this actually was the answer. It was tagged with windows 10, sorry if that wasn't specific enough for you @fixer1234 ;-)

Comment: @rpg711 Thank you, I'm glad I could help, and you just helped me too, as you at least helped me to be able to answer questions again. as for the windows version, I think I covered all my bases with it

Comment: @rpg711 as thanks (and confusion about the down-vote on the question) I have use my newly acquired voting priv to neutralize the downvote :) and it is a worthy question of at leat 2 votes

Comment: @DanHolli, congrats on the acceptance and accumulating some rep.  BTW, good answers can attract upvotes from many readers, and do so long after.  The feedback on this answer and the other one about what attracted downvotes or could in the future, was things that you can still go back and improve to make the answers more useful to the community at large (and apply the same principle on others).  Editing the answers will bump them on the main page, so it isn't like once the question is old, the opportunity is gone.

Comment: @fixer1234 I just posted an answer!!! I'm back on my way to helping others! started with a chromebook owner installing linux